# json schema mixing optional patternproperties with ref

Tags: jsonschema

I'm new to json schema.
I tried some complex mix and it doesn't work like I expected.
I have the following json:

```
{
  "aaa": {
    "Type": "Type1",
    "prop1": "val3"
  },
  "bbb": {
    "Type": "Type1",
    "prop2": "val4"
  }
}
```

The Idea is that the json contains jsons of objects with Type1 that have a variable key (property?) name and **may** contain another object (Type2 or Type 3) in it and the only mandatory property is Type with the value Type1

I tried to use the following schema to validate the json above:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "Type1": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "Type": {
          "const": "Type1"
        },
        "prop1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "prop2": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "patternProperties": {
        "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$": {
          "oneOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Type2"
            },
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Type3"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "Type"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "Type2": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "PropArr": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "Type": {
          "const": "Type2"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "PropArr",
        "Type"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "Type3": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "Prop": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "Type": {
          "const": "Type3"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "Prop",
        "Type"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },
  "patternProperties": {
    "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$": {
      "type": "object",
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Type1"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "minProperties": 1,
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

however I fail to validate this json because it doesn't contain type2 or type3 for type1 objects.
Is specifying "oneof" for pattern properties (in Type1) implies that it must contain the patterned property? is there a way to make that object optional in the schema?

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues and missconceptions here. That's OK.

I put your schema and JSON instance into an [online validator](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/). I find this super helpful to get immediate feedback as to why validation fails.

The approach you want to take is right, but the implementation is slightly off.

Starting at `patternProperties` after all of your definition, you've stated that each property (that matches the pattern) must have a value that is an object. Good. The object must be `Type1` which you've referenced correctly.

In your definition of `Type1`, you've used `properties` and `patternProperties`. `patternProperties` is being applied to the properties you've already specified in `properties` because it doesn't exclude those found in other "properties" based keywords. `additionalProperties` however, which may be a schema, only applies to those properties which haven't already been covered by `properties` and `patternProperties`.

> Validation with "additionalProperties" applies only to the child
> values of instance names that do not match any names in "properties",
> and do not match any regular expression in "patternProperties".

[Draft-7 validations `additionalProperties`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.5.6)

Hopefully this explanation and the link to the online validator (which provides helpful validation failure messages) will allow you to progress with your schema. It's a little difficult to give you a corrected schema when I can't see more possible instance json data.

Comment: JSON Schema has an official slack workspace which can be found via the website. It's open to all, and people are happy to help where they can, if you should need additional help!